# Remove &submit= in the URL having to differentiate among 2 _GET methods in the same page

Tags: php, forms, submit

I have 2 _GET methods, one shows the first result of the query and the second show a result of one of the result of the same query.

So yes, two GET methods which differ from their name and I can not change to POST because I need to have GET. One is submit and the other is xml.

I know which code to run thanks to:

```
IF( isset($_GET["submit"] )) {} or
IF( isset($_GET["xml"] )) {}
```

But the url for the main form is `http://localhost/index.php [...] &submit=`
because `<button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" id="submit">`.

For the xml one is okay. I want it to be `?xml=`.

**UPDATE**: How do I "convert" `IF( isset($_GET["submit"] )) {}` in order to have the same behaviour but without the name=submit, therefore removing `&submit=` in the URL ?

Comment: So what's the problem?!

Comment: Thanks, updated! I forgot to conclude it

Answer (score 0):

Remove the name attribute for the submit button that you don't want to submit the `name=value` pair of.

Then change the PHP so instead of asking "IF submit THEN. IF xml THEN" you ask: "IF xml THEN. ELSE."

Comment: Is it the only one solution.. right? Tried already but I'm having already other condition in the else and this would change the flow of the request.

I was hoping there was a method to use the id and not the name, or something that I could feed to the submit but the name.

Comment: @Nihvel — Only the name and value will be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, I needed anyway to insert another value to the form, a hidden one. So I'm using `IF(isset($_GET['page'])){}` instead of submit.

Removed the name from the submit button and added this hidden one.
At least I have my page variable now.